# Installing PHPUnit 5.4 with PHP 7.0.7 / Apache2.4 on Windows 10, Error : Could not open file phpunit.phar

Tags: php, apache, phpunit

I have setup x64 (TS - Thread Safe) version of PHP 7.0.7 with Apache 2.4 on my Windows 10 machine.
PHP is running fine.
I downloaded the phpunit.phar (PHPUnit 5.4) from https://phpunit.de/ , where it states that PHPUnit 5.4 is supported on PHP 7.
I have my Windows Environment Variable set so that PHP is accessible through command line.
When I execute the following command :

```
echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %* > phpunit.cmd
```

It generates the phpunit.cmd without any problem.

After that when I execute : phpunit --version

It gives me the error : Could not open file phpunit.phar

Has anyone  encountered a similar issue or is there anything I might be doing wrong?

Comment: generating it is one thing. did it generate the .cmd PROPERLY? have you looked at what's inside the .cmd?

Comment: This is what is inside phpunit.cmd : @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %* 
I also checked with one of my old PHPUnit Installations with PHP5.4, which had the same content.

Comment: Just a note all the required extensions are enabled, the ones by default, also the PHAR & OpenSSL extensions. It would be great to know if I can get some idea where I'm going wrong :)

Comment: `%~dp0` expands to the path leading up the .cmd file, so you're doing `c:\whatever\foo\bar\phpunit.phar`,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the filename of phpunit-5.4.4.phar to phpunit.phar.
As in the command it was :
echo @php "%~dp0phpunit.phar" %* > phpunit.cmd
So changing the filename to phpunit.phar fixes the issue & PHPUnit runs fine.

Cheers :)